# I'm not getting cube of the number

Tags: shell, files

```
while [ "$c" = y -o "$c" = Y -o -z $c ]
do
  echo enter a number;
  read n;
    if [ $n -ge 0 -a $n -le 50 ];then
      echo "cube= `expr $n * $n * $n`";
    fi;
  echo y to continue  or any to exit;
  read c;
done
```

Comment: To ask a better question, you should describe (or better, show) what actually happens, and describe how that differs from what you *want* to happen.

Answer (score 6):

You've got a few problems with your shell script. First, you should quote `$c` in the while (all of them — you missed the last one). Otherwise, when $c is empty (say, at the start of your program), the -z test gets passed nothing instead of the empty string, giving an error (something along the lines of "argument expected").

Second, you need to escape the `*` in your `expr` command. Otherwise it's trying to do a glob (match filenames), just like `cat *` would do. Easiest is to escape it to `\*`. The error from that will depend on exactly what the * happens to expand to (i.e., which files are in your current directory), but will probably be something confusing!

That should at least get your script to run.

PS: There are a bunch more ways this could be improved, you might want to check out [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for some (automated) suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you could write:

```
PS3="Continue? "
while true; do

    read -p "Enter a number: " n
    ((0 <= n && n <= 50)) && echo "cube = $((n * n * n))"

    select ans in yes no; do
        case $ans in
            yes) break ;;
            no) break 2 ;;
        esac
    done
done
```